# Meteor phone app persistent data

Tags: meteor, mobile

Is there a way for a Metoer mobile app to keep persistent data offline and between restarts? I've tried to find some info but can't find much about this. How would data then be resolved (be put back on the server, perhaps with conflicts).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! If found a link to a post that poses a solution using grounddb. Using the grounddb package supposidly also works accross app reloads. See the article here: http://rafaelquintanilha.com/offline-app-with-meteor-and-cordova/